# Rails scope params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

Trying to write a simple search using scope however I get a strange response and I was wondering if someone could explain my mistake.

```
  scope :sounds_like, -> (item) { where('title ILIKE ?', "#{ params[:sounds_like] }%")}
```

And my controller looks like

```
 def index
    @items = Item.sounds_like(params[:sounds_like])
 end
```

I get the following error when trying to search from an API.

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Class:0x00007ff553a054d8>):
```

Is there any way of passing the params to the model without using the params passed from the form?

Comment: Read carefully your code.

Comment: Your scope should reference its `item` parameter, not look at `params` (which is only available in controllers): `where('title ILIKE ?', "#{item}%")`. Presumably you originally wrote the scope's query in a controller method and then moved it to a scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the description provided following code will not work:

```
scope :sounds_like, -> (item) { where('title ILIKE ?', "#{ params[:sounds_like] }%")}
```

since params are not available in the model.

Modify the above written scope to something mentioned below:

```
scope :sounds_like, -> (item) { where('title ILIKE ?', "%#{item}%") }
```

In the above mentioned scope the item will be the argument you will be passing from the controller.

Answer (score 3):

In Rails models are not *request aware* - they don't have access to the params, the request object or the session.

To pass parameters from the controller to a model you pass them as method arguments:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord

  def self.sounds_like(value)
    where('title ILIKE ?', "#{ value }%")
  end
end

# call it as:
Thing.sounds_like('foo')
```

[`scope` is just a syntactic sugar](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) that lets you write class methods concisely. So the above would be written as:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  scope :sounds_like, ->(value){ where('title ILIKE ?', "#{ value }%")}
end
```

The second argument to `scope` is a [lambda](https://www.culttt.com/2015/05/13/what-are-lambdas-in-ruby/) - which is an anonymous function which acts like a method:

```
irb(main):001:0> l = -> (v) { puts v }
=> #<Proc:0x007f81dca27d48@(irb):1 (lambda)>
irb(main):002:0> l.call("Hello World")
Hello World
=> nil
```

The parens denotes the arguments of the lambda just like when defining methods:

```
irb(main):016:0> lamb = -> (a, b) { [a,b].join(" ") }
=> #<Proc:0x007f81dc983ec8@(irb):16 (lambda)>
irb(main):017:0> lamb.call("Hello", "World")
=> "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this on your scope

```
scope :sounds_like, -> (item) { where('title ILIKE ?', "%#{item}%") }
```

It should work.

Further information about rails scope you can see this [article](https://devblast.com/b/jutsu-11-rails-scopes)